# How can I get a detailed array from another observable of array

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I am beginner in RxSwift in general trying to chain two different  operation with my REST API to get all detailed products.

I wrapped some REST API to return RxSwift Observable, one return a list of product and other the product detail.

```
class API {
    func listProduct() -> Observable<[Product]> { ... }
    func detailProdcut(code: Int) -> Observable<[ProductDetail]> { ... }
}
```

Now I want to get the product detail from a product list, how can I do this in Rx way ? I'm trying to do something like

```
API.init().listProduct()
    .flapMap { products -> <Product> in return products[0] }
    .map { product in API.init(product.code) }
    .merge()
    .toArray
```

But isn't work, and I very confused about how to transform one list of products code into an array of products detail

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
let api = API()

let productDetails = api.listProducts()
  .flatMap { products in
    let productsObservable = Observable.from(products)
    let productDetails = productsObservable.flatMap { api.detail(product($0.code) }

    return productDetails.toArray()
  }
```

What is going on here :

- `flatMap` has specialized type `[Product] -> Observable<[ProductDetails]>`. How? Read on.
- [`Observable.from`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/3c55a309a24fbe3dbc480431798eec072b633b85/RxSwift/Observables/Observable%2BCreation.swift#L189) takes a swift array and transforms it into an observable. It will emit next event for each of the element of the array. So we now have `Observable<Product>` in `productsObservable`.
- the call to `flatMap` on `productObservable` will create an `Observable<ProductDetail>` for each next event it sends. We now have an observable that will send as many next event as their are products in the result of `listProducts`.
- We use [`toArray`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/3c55a309a24fbe3dbc480431798eec072b633b85/RxSwift/Observables/Observable%2BAggregate.swift#L57) to transform this observable to something that will emit only **one** next event, an array aggregating all the results from `productDetails`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now transforming data became clear for me on reactive programming.